# change column status in JIRA in existing board

Tags: jira, status

We're using JIRA for our development team. After an reorganizational fit, the status and name of several columns in the board do not correspond any longer. Our board consists of an Simplified Workflow.

My question: what are the consequences of changing the status of one or more columns? Does it affect the history of issues already completed, i.e. will searching for them be more difficult?